# Linear section of an algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $\pi$ be a linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^n$ and $X$ a reduced, irreducible variety of $\mathbb{P}^n$. Suppose that $\pi\cap X$ is reducible, hence $\pi\cap X=Y_1∪Y_2∪⋯Y_k$. When the degree of $Y_i$ is "small", i.e., when $d<\dim\pi−\dim Y_i+1$, then we have that $⟨Y_i⟩⊊π$. My question is: can we have $⟨Y_i⟩⊊π$ if $d≥\dim π−\dim Y_i+1$?

Comment: Of course: pick a plane $\pi$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ containing a line $L=Y_1$ that lies in a smooth cubic hypersurface $X$. Then the residual intersection is generically a smooth conic $Y_2$ whose degree is $2=\text{dim} \pi - \text{dim} Y__2 + 1$

Comment: Yes, that was trivial...but one of the two components has degree small. So it would be possible that a quartic hypersurface of $\mathbb{P}^3$ has a plane section decomposible in two conics?

Comment: Ok then, yes, let's try a quartic. Take the quartic $X=V((yz-x^2)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)-w^4)$. It's reduced and irreducible and intersecting it with the plane $(w=0)$ yields a union of two smooth conics.

Comment: actually my question was different: when a variety $Y_i$ does not span $\pi$. In your example the line does not span $\pi$ because the degree is small. The conic spans the plane!